# Pre-chilled spirits - is there a content difference?

Tags: gin

Normally I would add ice to a glass, then a piece of lime, pour (in my case) gin over the ice, then top it off with tonic.  However, a friend of mind chills their gin in the fridge, but also pours their drink in exactly the same manner.  So, my question is:  If I pre-chill my gin in the fridge does it have any effect on it, such as taste (other than having a much colder drink)?

Comment: Just realised that this is a similar question to one below - any problems and I will happily remove it.

Comment: Dilution would be a big factor.

Comment: Even if you both drink your gin over ice, since hers is cooler to begin with, the ice will melt slower

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how cold your gin would be served at, it aromas may be altered.

As a spirit gets warmer, it releases more volatiles, compounds that easily vaporize. We know that if a spirit is too hot, the smell of pure alcohol can be overwhelming. However, when a spirit is too cold, the aromas and tastes might seem downright non-existent. This applies to whiskeys and gins especially.

Cold gins may be okay for some, but I prefer to be able to truly taste my gins. That is why I would only add ice to it, if I had to. Even at that, I truly doubt anyone in my family would chill their gin or put ice in it.

But then, to each his own!

Comment: Agree with this. Hence would chill cheap gin but drink good gin just at room temperature (probably with refrigerated tonic so that the drink ends up a little below room temperature)